# Windows pipe hanging

Tags: java, windows, pipe

This is a frustrating problem. I'm running the following Java code:

```
       try {
            String query = someQuery, input = someInput;
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", query); // Windows
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            try
            {
                // Input to the query
                OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
                os.write(input.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
            }

            System.out.println("STDIN : \n");

            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`query` is a piped command.  Each sub-command within `query` is a unix-like API call (proprietary : Sirsi Unicorn API if anyone's interested); also it is a database call. The windows command prompt can accomodate these API calls.

**PROBLEM:**

If I try piping 2 database commands, the program runs successfully, but if I pipe 3 database commands, the program just hangs. If these same commands are run on cygwin, the program works fine. Interestingly, if I break the 3 pipe command into two separate commands, the program runs fine.

**QUESTION:**

My question is- is there a pipe buffer problem on the windows command line? Are there instances where piping on windows won't work? Can piping time out?

At this point, any info is appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without Java (from a shell)?

Comment: Yeah. Even the shell gives up. I just can't figure this one out! The commands are in such a way that the the output of one is fed as the input to another via a pipe. e.g.,
selitem -iK -oN | selcharge -iN -oSH

Comment: so in the example above, the selitem command outputs N, which is fed as the input to selcharge. you can choose to output a bunch of stuff. e.g.,
selitem -iK -oNSKB | selcharge -iN -oSH

Comment: For future reference, your Java code needs to use multiple threads.  With your current code, you're not reading from the stdInput pipe until you've finished writing all your queries.  This means that if the stdInput pipe becomes full, the subprocess won't be able to write any new data; in most cases, the subprocess will stop reading data until it can finish the pending write.  If the output pipe then fills up, your code deadlocks.  Of course, this doesn't explain the problem you're experiencing on the command line.

Comment: On the command line, how does the first command in the pipeline know when you've finished providing input?  How does the pipeline fail on the command line - does it hang?  If so, are all of the commands still running (use task manager) or only some of them?